# Why doesn't the tensorflow sentiment classification tutorial work as expected?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to run this movie review classification example copied from here:
https://colab.research.google.com/github/google-research/bert/blob/master/predicting_movie_reviews_with_bert_on_tf_hub.ipynb

But got an error message:

```
  File "/Users/congminmin/nlp/ml-test/bert/my_bert.py", line 183, in model_fn
    (loss, predicted_labels, log_probs) = create_model(
  File "/Users/congminmin/nlp/ml-test/bert/my_bert.py", line 131, in create_model
    hidden_size = output_layer.shape[-1].value
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'value'
```

I am running in my local environment with TF 2.5, python 3.8. The original code seems only work with TF1.x, so I made a few changes by adding '.compat.v1.' to several functions, i.e. tf.compat.v1.logging. Other than that, I don't make any changes. The full code is below copied from the tutorial.

Why is the output_layer's shape is incorrect in this tutorial? I don't think this only work with TF1 but not TF2. The error comes from the 'create_model' function.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
from datetime import datetime

import bert
from bert import run_classifier
from bert import optimization
from bert import tokenization

from tensorflow import keras
import os
import re


# Load all files from a directory in a DataFrame.
def load_directory_data(directory):
    data = {}
    data["sentence"] = []
    data["sentiment"] = []
    for file_path in os.listdir(directory):
        with tf.compat.v1.gfile.GFile(os.path.join(directory, file_path), "r") as f:
            data["sentence"].append(f.read())
            data["sentiment"].append(re.match("\d+_(\d+)\.txt", file_path).group(1))
    return pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)


# Merge positive and negative examples, add a polarity column and shuffle.
def load_dataset(directory):
    pos_df = load_directory_data(os.path.join(directory, "pos"))
    neg_df = load_directory_data(os.path.join(directory, "neg"))
    pos_df["polarity"] = 1
    neg_df["polarity"] = 0
    return pd.concat([pos_df, neg_df]).sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)


# Download and process the dataset files.
def download_and_load_datasets(force_download=False):
    dataset = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
        fname="aclImdb.tar.gz",
        origin="http://ai.stanford.edu/~amaas/data/sentiment/aclImdb_v1.tar.gz",
        extract=True)

    train_df = load_dataset(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(dataset),
                                         "aclImdb", "train"))
    test_df = load_dataset(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(dataset),
                                        "aclImdb", "test"))

    return train_df, test_df

print('Download data ... ')
train, test = download_and_load_datasets()

train = train.sample(5000)
test = test.sample(5000)
print('print columns ...')
print(train.columns)

DATA_COLUMN = 'sentence'
LABEL_COLUMN = 'polarity'
# label_list is the list of labels, i.e. True, False or 0, 1 or 'dog', 'cat'
label_list = [0, 1]

print('Create input examples ...')
# Use the InputExample class from BERT's run_classifier code to create examples from the data
train_InputExamples = train.apply(lambda x: bert.run_classifier.InputExample(guid=None, # Globally unique ID for bookkeeping, unused in this example
                                                                   text_a = x[DATA_COLUMN],
                                                                   text_b = None,
                                                                   label = x[LABEL_COLUMN]), axis = 1)

test_InputExamples = test.apply(lambda x: bert.run_classifier.InputExample(guid=None,
                                                                   text_a = x[DATA_COLUMN],
                                                                   text_b = None,
                                                                   label = x[LABEL_COLUMN]), axis = 1)

# This is a path to an uncased (all lowercase) version of BERT
BERT_MODEL_HUB = "https://tfhub.dev/google/bert_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/1"

# This is a path to an uncased (all lowercase) version of BERT
BERT_MODEL_HUB = "https://tfhub.dev/google/bert_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/1"


def create_tokenizer_from_hub_module():
    """Get the vocab file and casing info from the Hub module."""
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        bert_module = hub.Module(BERT_MODEL_HUB)
        tokenization_info = bert_module(signature="tokenization_info", as_dict=True)
        with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
            vocab_file, do_lower_case = sess.run([tokenization_info["vocab_file"],
                                                  tokenization_info["do_lower_case"]])

    return bert.tokenization.FullTokenizer(
        vocab_file=vocab_file, do_lower_case=do_lower_case)


tokenizer = create_tokenizer_from_hub_module()

print('Download module and create tokenizer ...')
tokenizer = create_tokenizer_from_hub_module()

print(tokenizer.tokenize("This here's an example of using the BERT tokenizer"))

# We'll set sequences to be at most 128 tokens long.
# We'll set sequences to be at most 128 tokens long.
MAX_SEQ_LENGTH = 128
# Convert our train and test features to InputFeatures that BERT understands.
train_features = bert.run_classifier.convert_examples_to_features(train_InputExamples, label_list, MAX_SEQ_LENGTH, tokenizer)
test_features = bert.run_classifier.convert_examples_to_features(test_InputExamples, label_list, MAX_SEQ_LENGTH, tokenizer)

def create_model(is_predicting, input_ids, input_mask, segment_ids, labels,
                 num_labels):
  """Creates a classification model."""

  bert_module = hub.Module(
      BERT_MODEL_HUB,
      trainable=True)
  bert_inputs = dict(
      input_ids=input_ids,
      input_mask=input_mask,
      segment_ids=segment_ids)
  bert_outputs = bert_module(
      inputs=bert_inputs,
      signature="tokens",
      as_dict=True)

  # Use "pooled_output" for classification tasks on an entire sentence.
  # Use "sequence_outputs" for token-level output.
  output_layer = bert_outputs["pooled_output"]

  hidden_size = output_layer.shape[-1].value

  # Create our own layer to tune for politeness data.
  output_weights = tf.compat.v1.get_variable(
      "output_weights", [num_labels, hidden_size],
      initializer=tf.compat.v1.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.02))

  output_bias = tf.compat.v1.get_variable(
      "output_bias", [num_labels], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())

  with tf.compat.v1.variable_scope("loss"):

    # Dropout helps prevent overfitting
    output_layer = tf.nn.dropout(output_layer, keep_prob=0.9)

    logits = tf.matmul(output_layer, output_weights, transpose_b=True)
    logits = tf.nn.bias_add(logits, output_bias)
    log_probs = tf.nn.log_softmax(logits, axis=-1)

    # Convert labels into one-hot encoding
    one_hot_labels = tf.one_hot(labels, depth=num_labels, dtype=tf.float32)

    predicted_labels = tf.squeeze(tf.argmax(log_probs, axis=-1, output_type=tf.int32))
    # If we're predicting, we want predicted labels and the probabiltiies.
    if is_predicting:
      return (predicted_labels, log_probs)

    # If we're train/eval, compute loss between predicted and actual label
    per_example_loss = -tf.reduce_sum(one_hot_labels * log_probs, axis=-1)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(per_example_loss)
    return (loss, predicted_labels, log_probs)


# model_fn_builder actually creates our model function
# using the passed parameters for num_labels, learning_rate, etc.
def model_fn_builder(num_labels, learning_rate, num_train_steps,
                     num_warmup_steps):
    """Returns `model_fn` closure for TPUEstimator."""

    def model_fn(features, labels, mode, params):  # pylint: disable=unused-argument
        """The `model_fn` for TPUEstimator."""

        input_ids = features["input_ids"]
        input_mask = features["input_mask"]
        segment_ids = features["segment_ids"]
        label_ids = features["label_ids"]

        is_predicting = (mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT)

        # TRAIN and EVAL
        if not is_predicting:

            (loss, predicted_labels, log_probs) = create_model(
                is_predicting, input_ids, input_mask, segment_ids, label_ids, num_labels)

            train_op = bert.optimization.create_optimizer(
                loss, learning_rate, num_train_steps, num_warmup_steps, use_tpu=False)

            # Calculate evaluation metrics.
            def metric_fn(label_ids, predicted_labels):
                accuracy = tf.metrics.accuracy(label_ids, predicted_labels)
                f1_score = tf.contrib.metrics.f1_score(
                    label_ids,
                    predicted_labels)
                auc = tf.metrics.auc(
                    label_ids,
                    predicted_labels)
                recall = tf.metrics.recall(
                    label_ids,
                    predicted_labels)
                precision = tf.metrics.precision(
                    label_ids,
                    predicted_labels)
                true_pos = tf.metrics.true_positives(
                    label_ids,
                    predicted_labels)
                true_neg = tf.metrics.true_negatives(
                    label_ids,
                    predicted_labels)
                false_pos = tf.metrics.false_positives(
                    label_ids,
                    predicted_labels)
                false_neg = tf.metrics.false_negatives(
                    label_ids,
                    predicted_labels)
                return {
                    "eval_accuracy": accuracy,
                    "f1_score": f1_score,
                    "auc": auc,
                    "precision": precision,
                    "recall": recall,
                    "true_positives": true_pos,
                    "true_negatives": true_neg,
                    "false_positives": false_pos,
                    "false_negatives": false_neg
                }

            eval_metrics = metric_fn(label_ids, predicted_labels)

            if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
                return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode,
                                                  loss=loss,
                                                  train_op=train_op)
            else:
                return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode,
                                                  loss=loss,
                                                  eval_metric_ops=eval_metrics)
        else:
            (predicted_labels, log_probs) = create_model(
                is_predicting, input_ids, input_mask, segment_ids, label_ids, num_labels)

            predictions = {
                'probabilities': log_probs,
                'labels': predicted_labels
            }
            return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, predictions=predictions)

    # Return the actual model function in the closure
    return model_fn

# Compute train and warmup steps from batch size
# These hyperparameters are copied from this colab notebook (https://colab.sandbox.google.com/github/tensorflow/tpu/blob/master/tools/colab/bert_finetuning_with_cloud_tpus.ipynb)
BATCH_SIZE = 32
LEARNING_RATE = 2e-5
NUM_TRAIN_EPOCHS = 3.0
# Warmup is a period of time where hte learning rate
# is small and gradually increases--usually helps training.
WARMUP_PROPORTION = 0.1
# Model configs
SAVE_CHECKPOINTS_STEPS = 500
SAVE_SUMMARY_STEPS = 100

# Compute # train and warmup steps from batch size
num_train_steps = int(len(train_features) / BATCH_SIZE * NUM_TRAIN_EPOCHS)
num_warmup_steps = int(num_train_steps * WARMUP_PROPORTION)

# Specify outpit directory and number of checkpoint steps to save
run_config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(
    model_dir='output_dir',
    save_summary_steps=SAVE_SUMMARY_STEPS,
    save_checkpoints_steps=SAVE_CHECKPOINTS_STEPS)

model_fn = model_fn_builder(
  num_labels=len(label_list),
  learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE,
  num_train_steps=num_train_steps,
  num_warmup_steps=num_warmup_steps)

estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(
  model_fn=model_fn,
  config=run_config,
  params={"batch_size": BATCH_SIZE})

# Create an input function for training. drop_remainder = True for using TPUs.
train_input_fn = bert.run_classifier.input_fn_builder(
    features=train_features,
    seq_length=MAX_SEQ_LENGTH,
    is_training=True,
    drop_remainder=False)

print(f'Beginning Training!')
current_time = datetime.now()
estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, max_steps=num_train_steps)
print("Training took time ", datetime.now() - current_time)

test_input_fn = run_classifier.input_fn_builder(
    features=test_features,
    seq_length=MAX_SEQ_LENGTH,
    is_training=False,
    drop_remainder=False)

print('Do testing ...')
estimator.evaluate(input_fn=test_input_fn, steps=None)

def getPrediction(in_sentences):
  labels = ["Negative", "Positive"]
  input_examples = [run_classifier.InputExample(guid="", text_a = x, text_b = None, label = 0) for x in in_sentences] # here, "" is just a dummy label
  input_features = run_classifier.convert_examples_to_features(input_examples, label_list, MAX_SEQ_LENGTH, tokenizer)
  predict_input_fn = run_classifier.input_fn_builder(features=input_features, seq_length=MAX_SEQ_LENGTH, is_training=False, drop_remainder=False)
  predictions = estimator.predict(predict_input_fn)
  return [(sentence, prediction['probabilities'], labels[prediction['labels']]) for sentence, prediction in zip(in_sentences, predictions)]

pred_sentences = [
  "That movie was absolutely awful",
  "The acting was a bit lacking",
  "The film was creative and surprising",
  "Absolutely fantastic!"
]

predictions = getPrediction(pred_sentences)

print(predictions)
```

EDIT: per suggestion, the 'no attribute value' error was fixed by removing the 'value'. More changes need to be made to make it work with TF 2.0, and this one caused another error:

```
train_op = bert.optimization.create_optimizer(
            loss, learning_rate, num_train_steps, num_warmup_steps, use_tpu=False)


File "/Users/congminmin/nlp/ml-test/bert/my_bert.py", line 187, in model_fn
    train_op = bert.optimization.create_optimizer(
  File "/Users/congminmin/nlp/ml-test/bert/optimization.py", line 27, in create_optimizer
    global_step = tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v2.train' has no attribute 'get_or_create_global_step'
```

How to modify the way to get the train_op variable in TF2 from TF1?

Comment: This ``output_layer.shape[-1]`` returns an integer (last dimension), and an integer has not a ``value`` attribute. Remove the ``.value``.

Comment: You answered your own question. You are using outdated code. There have been more changes from 1.x and 2.x that cannot be fixed by just slapping `tf.compat.v1` everywhere. I would really suggest not using outdated tutorials, or installing TF 1.x if you must.

Comment: @Kaveh. Please see my update. There is a new error.

Comment: @xdurch0 The problem with this tutorial to use old TF was that it also uses TF Hub, which requires TF 2.0.